# JAVA - SPARK - saveAsTextFile can not be applied to '(java.lang.String, org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec)'

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

Im writing a program in JAVA with Spark.

I have an JavaRDD named "copied_logs" which uses map and copies several fields from logs that are at on the hdfs.

now, I want to compress "copied_logs" with Bzip2 and then save it.
i want to save this data on the hdfs using "saveAsTextFile" function.
my code for compressing and saving is as follows:

```
    CompressionCodec codec = new BZip2Codec();
    copied_logs.saveAsTextFile(output_dir + "copied_logs.json", codec);
```

but i get this error:

```
Error:(128, 69) java: incompatible types: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of the method `saveAsTextFile` is a Class type ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#saveAsTextFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class))). Therefore, you need to pass the .class object.

Something like:

```
copied_logs.saveAsTextFile(output_dir + "copied_logs.json", BZip2Codec.class)
```